# Как в js сделать подгрузку определенного контента

Tags: html, css, javascript

Привет всем. Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, а то я уже неделю не могу ничего найти. Нужен скрипт асинхронной загрусзки страницы. К примеру, когда полностью открылась страница сайта, появлялась надпись `"Подождите идет загрузка"`, и через секунд 2 - 3 появлялся контент сайта (в моем случаи это блоги).

Comment: jquery юзать не хотите?

Answer (score 1):

Вот простое решение - попап с самозакрытием. Сейчас он конечно крайне примитивен, просто как вариант:

```
<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#popup { position: absolute; background: red; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 100; }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( 'body' ).prepend( '<div id="popup">Downloading... please wait!</div>' );
   setTimeout(function() { $( '#popup' ).remove(); }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Можно сделать закрытие не через фиксированное время а по *onload*, когда контент прогрузится.

Comment: Неверное решение, нужно сделать не через три секунды а после полной загрузки html страницы. А то вдруг может у кого инет тормоз

Comment: я в js ноль так что не могли бы вы YOUIX html прописать а то я не знаю что с ним делать

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/7998/bemulima почему не верно??! Как написал автор, можно на onload повесить и все!!

Answer (score 0):

Используя jQuery попробуйте на событие загрузки повесить текст о том, что страница загружается.
А когда страница загрузится - выводите контент.